# Overwrite a variable when an other variable turns false Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables

I'm working on an angular project and I was wondering if there is a proper way to do this:

I have a variable called *signed*, its basically a boolean. Its binded to a checkbox. I also have a variable called *grade*, its an integer, binded to a number input.

I want *signed* to automatically turn true when *grade* changes to >=2, also I want *grade* to automatically turn "1" when *signed* changes to false. (Right now I'm manually calling two functions to check and set the other variable.)

Any ideas?

update: Forgot to mention that I actually have multiple *subjects*, each has a signed and grade property and obviously a *subject*'s property should not be affected by another *subject*'s property's change

Comment: You'll want to either use `ng-change`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange or `ngModelOptions`'s `getterSetter`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: ng-change is how I manually call the functions which do the job. I don't see how getterSetter would help me

Comment: The function you give to `getterSetter` gets called every time the view changes but it's kind of overkill for what you want so I think what you are currently doing with `ng-change` is the best approach. `ng-change` won't result in a new watcher being created where `$watch` will so I think `ng-change` is a better aproach than `$watch`

Answer (score 0):

something like this with `ng-change`

Html:

```
<input ng-model="subjects.a.grade" ng-change="changeGrade('a')">
<input ng-model="subjects.a.signed" ng-change="changeSigned('a')">
```

Inside your controller :

```
$scope.subjects = {'a' : {'signed' :false, 'grade' : 1} ,
                  'b' : {'signed' :false, 'grade' : 2} };

$scope.changeGrade = function(s){
    if($scope.subjects[s].grade >=2  ){
        $scope.subjects[s].signed = true ;
    }
}

$scope.changeSigned = function(s){
    if(!$scope.subjects[s].signed){
        $scope.subjects[s].grade = 1 ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I actually have multiple subjects, each has a _signed_ and _grade_ property and obviously a subject's property should not be affected by another subject's property's change

Comment: This is exactly the solution what I use now. Thought there is a better way.

Comment: @fureszk, how much better could it get? Unless you write some directive to make it seem like magic, this is minimal code. Plus then you have to maintain the directive. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

why NOT use functions? Like so :

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.signed" ng-change="updateGrade()" />
     <input type="number"   ng-model="data.grade"  ng-change="updateSigned()" />

 </div>
```

and

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.data = 
     {
       grade  : 2, 
       signed : false
     }; 

    $scope.updateGrade 
       = function()  {  this.data.grade  = !this.data.signed ?  1 : this.data.grade; }

    $scope.updateSigned 
       = function() {  this.data.signed =  this.data.grade  >= 2  ? true : false;   }

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k1dbl4ck/HB7LU/21953/

in other words, it will take more code later on reading values from those inputs than just binding them in the beginning and having direct access to the $scope.data model from anywhere.

Comment: yep, this is what I do now, I was curios if there is a better, more proper way to do it

Comment: if you have multiple input for `signed`, has @fureszk says, you have to pass the containing var to the function ( as i do in my response )